# Что означает запись !adc.Start() и что такое таймаут у АЦП?

Tags: c#

Что означает запись `!adc.Start()`?
И что имеется в виду под понятием "таймаут" для АЦП?  Параметр такой задается `adc.Timeout`. А зачем он нужен непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!adc.Start()`

Выражение, возвращающее `true`, если метод `adc.Start` вернул `false`, и `true`, если этот метод вернул `false`.

Таймаут - это время, в течение которого предполагается ожидать завершения некоторой операции. Например, ожидание ответа от сервера. Если сервер в течение времени, указанного в таймауте, не ответил, бросается исключение.

Comment: Только АЦП -- это не сервер, а устройство. И если до истечения таймаута вы не получили результат, значит что-то не работает. И программа должна по этому поводу что-то предпринять.